# This program can't start because freeglut.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, freeglut

I recently started using freeglut, and it worked fine when I built it and ran it (I'm using Code::Blocks, by the way), but when I went to the debugged exe, it says: "This program can't start because freeglut.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I read that freeglut.dll should be in the same folder, and it worked, but is there any way to include it with the exe so it could be portable, I'm pretty novice at C++, so thanks for any help :)

Comment: Add the directory where `freeglut.dll` was installed to your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Use an installer to ensure that the dll is available in the exe folder?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to configure your linker to link in the libraries static.

Comment: Static links are not considered to be the best choice but they are the easiest way of deploying without an installer.

Answer (score 1):

Have to give credit to @πάντα ῥεῖ, for suggesting this first, but I felt that it should be an answer too. If you don't want to statically link the libraries, you can just add the path to the freeglut.dll file to your path. This is done (one a session basis) by executing `set path=%path%;[PATH_TO_FREEGLUT_DOT_DLL]` in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit machine try putting freeglut.dll into c:\windows\syswow64 folder, for some reason it didn't work in my system32 folder